# Degeneration of energy levels, hamiltonian with $S_x^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

I've got a hamiltonian $H=\lambda S_x^2$, where $S_x$ denotes the operator for the x component of the particle spin. The particle is said to  have a spin of size $S=1$. The question is: find the eigenvalues of $H$ and the degeneration of the corresponding energy levels.

I look for eigenvalues of the hamiltonian using $H|\psi\rangle$=$E|\psi \rangle$ , I write a general eigenfunction in the $|S,S_z\rangle$ basis in the form $|\psi\rangle = a|1,1\rangle + b |1,0\rangle +c|1,-1\rangle$, by rewriting the hamiltonian using the $L_+$ and $L_-$ operators, $H=\lambda \frac{1}{4}(L_+ + L_-)^2$, I get $a=-2\frac{1}{\sqrt5}$, $b=0$ and $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} $ and a single energy eigenvalue.

$L_{\pm}|L,m\rangle=\hbar \sqrt{l(l+1)-m(m\pm 1)}|l,m\pm 1\rangle$

**My question**: Am I missing something or is it just a trick question and there is no degeneration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is strange. By a rotation , spectrum ( not eigenvectors that gets rotated of course ) is same as for Hamiltonian with $S_z^2$. So you get zero ( non degenerate) and $\lambda$ with degeneracy 2 from spectrum of $S_z=-1,0,1$.

Comment: You're right! I should have rotated the coordinate system to obtain the eigenvalues!!

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely missing something, since any eigenvector of $S_x$ should also be an eigenvector of $S_x^2$ and there are three eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $S_x$.

I suspect the error is in your diagonalization procedure, since everything in your question up to the definition of $H$ is correct.  However, by my calculations, the state
$$
|\psi \rangle = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} | +1 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} | -1 \rangle
$$
is *not* an eigenvector of $S_x^2$.